# How can I concatenate multiple lists in one dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have an OrderedDict with multiple values for the same city that I need to merge in one single dictionary. The OrderedDict goes as follows:

```
print(OrderedDict)
```

> OrderedDict([('UF' , 'New York'), ('Total', 44.13), ('DEF', 9.5)])
>
> OrderedDict([('UF' , 'LA'), ('Total', 54.13), ('DEF', 1.0)])
>
> OrderedDict([('UF' , 'New York'), ('Total', 12.01), ('DEF', 0.4)])
>
> ...

So I need a new dictionary where all the values for "New York" are summed into a single entry:

```
for data in OrderedDict:
    newDict = {"UF": data['UF'], 'DEF' : data["DEF"] , 'N_DEF' : (data["Total"] - data["DEF"]) , 'Total' : data["Total"] }
```

Here I'm not even doing the sum yet and I already having trouble, the for loop here is only returning 1 entry in the newDict, seem like it's not iterating through the hole OrderedDict.

```
print(newDict)
```

> {"DEF" : 9.5, "N_DEF" : 34,63 , "Total" : 44.13 , "UF" : "New York"}

Please help!!!!

Thanks people!!

Comment: You're rebinding the name `newDict` to a new value every iteration of the loop.

Comment: That's is absolutely true sir. I haven't realized that, still, don't know how to do it. =/

Comment: What would you expect the output for these inputs to be?

Comment: I expect to make a newDict with all the inputs of the OrderedDict but without the city duplicates and also summimg the values of total and def of the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an empty dict outside the for loop, and then update that with the values of each of your input dictioanries.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l=[OrderedDict([('UF' , 'New York'), ('Total', 44.13), ('DEF', 9.5)]),
   OrderedDict([('UF' , 'LA'), ('Total', 54.13), ('DEF', 1.0)]),
   OrderedDict([('UF' , 'New York'), ('Total', 12.01), ('DEF', 0.4)])]

d = {}
for od in l:
    city = od['UF']
    if city not in d:
        d[city] = od
    else:
        d[city]['DEF'] += od['DEF']
        d[city]['Total'] += od['Total']

print(d)
# {'New York': OrderedDict([('UF', 'New York'), ('Total', 68.15), ('DEF', 10.3)]), 
#  'LA': OrderedDict([('UF', 'LA'), ('Total', 54.13), ('DEF', 1.0)])}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. That was really helpful.